# C# DateTime when the user open a page

Tags: c#, session, variables, datetime

I want to take the DateTime of the user's connection. I guess I will use the Session variable because I don't want that the DateTime changes at every refresh of my page.

Maybe something like that :

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["dateandhour"] = DateTime.Now.Day + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month + "-" + DateTime.Now.Year + "." + DateTime.Now.Hour + "." + DateTime.Now.Minute + "." + DateTime.Now.Second;
}

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string hour= (string)(Session["dateandhour"]);
        lab10.Text = hour;

     }
```

Comment: That looks great. What's the question?

Comment: What is the actual question here? Great you want to set the datetime as a variable. But what is the actual problem?

Comment: Better is to save in a db table the user login time. As the other two people i want to ask what is the question?

Comment: You might want to change that DateTime string to `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy.HH.mms.s")`. Looks much better.

Comment: I don't want that the Date Time changes at every action of the user. In fact, I just want to save in a variable session Date Time when the user open the page

Answer (score 0):

You can save the DateTime directly:

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["dateandhour"] = DateTime.Now;
}

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime time = (DateTime)(Session["dateandhour"]);
    lab10.Text = time.Hour;
}
```

This greatly simplifies subsequent use of the data.

Comment: I don't want that the Date Time changes at every action of the user. In fact, I just want to save in a variable session  Date Time when the user open the page.

Comment: Thank for you reply !
How can i convert this "time.Hour;" to string ?

Comment: What you want is rather this: "lab10.Text = time.Tostring("dd-MM-yyyy.hh.mm.ss");"